# Web speech api recognition word in sentence

Tags: webspeech-api

I try with my programm to recognise a specific word when I speek a sentence, it's use Web speech API.

When I speek the word alone, my programm work fine, but when I speek it in a sentence, my programm doesn't run.

Thank's to tell me where is the problem with my programm.

```
<script>
    (function($)
    {
        var $btn = $('#btn');
        var $result = $('#result');
        var words = null;
        if ('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window)
        {
            var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
            recognition.lang = "fr-FR";
            recognition.continuous = false;
            recognition.interimResults = true;
            $btn.click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                $btn.removeClass('btn-primary');
                recognition.start();
            });
            recognition.onresult = function (event)
            {
                $result.text('');
                for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++)
                {
                    var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
                    if (event.results[i].isFinal)
                    {
                        $result.text(transcript);
                        recognition.stop();
                        $btn.addClass('btn-primary');
                        words = transcript.split(' ');
                        if(words[0] == 'test')
                        {
                            // do something                   
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $result.text($('#result').text() + event.results[i][0].transcript);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        else{$btn.hide();}
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `words = transcript.split(' ')` you make words an array of all of the recognized words. Then when you do `if(words[0] == 'test')` you are only checking the first word, so it will only work if the word you are trying to recognize is the first (or only) word.

Instead of this:

```
if(words[0] == 'test')
{
    // do something
}
```

Try this:

```
words.some(function (word) {
    if (word === 'test') {

        // do something

        return true;
    }
});
```